At impasse with my teacher about this derivative of this composite function
My teacher and I cannot agree about the derivative of this composite function:
$$ f(x) = (x-5)^\frac{2}{3} $$
$$ g(x) = 5\:\:\:for\:\:\:3 \leq x \leq 6 $$
$$ h(x) = f(g(x)) $$
$$ h'(4) = ? $$
My argument is that because $g(x)$ is constant on $[3,6]$, $f(g(x))$ or $h(x)$ must also be constant on that interval, and because $f(5)$ is defined, $h(x) = f(g(x)) = f(5)$ for $3 \le x \le 6$, and since $f(5)$ is constant by the definition of a function, $h'(x) = 0$ for $3 \lt x \lt 6$.
My teacher says that when the chain rule is used, $h'(4) = f '(5) \times g'(4)$ is of the form $\infty \times 0$, and thus the derivative DNE.
I am fairly confident that the derivative is simple enough when using the definition of a derivative, but how can I prove this answer through the chain rule, or explain why the chain rule is not a valid explanation for problems of this sort?
Furthermore, would my generalization hold that if $g(x) = k$ on $[a,b]$, where $k$ is a constant, and $f[k]$ is defined, and if a function $h(x)$ was defined as $f(g(x))$, then $h'(x) = 0$ on $(a,b)$?

Your teacher is wrong, you’re right.  The chain rule holds when both derivatives exist; but the failure of one or the other to exist doesn’t mean the original function isn’t differentiable.  Just means you can’t apply the chain rule.

Exactly analogous to $1/x \cdot x$ having a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, even though $1/x$ does not.

The composed function is constant on the interval $[3,6]$, mapping any number there to $0$. The derivative is therefore zero. As said before (and like any result in math),  the chain rule requires some assumptions and if they do not hold its consequence may not be valid.

Thank you, would the generalization below also hold in the same way due to all inputs (over the interval where the inner function is constant) being mapped to the same value?

In addition to the misapplication of the chain rule, in general $\infty\cdot0$ is called an indeterminate form because it doesn't determine an answer. In particular, it can't tell you that a limit does not exist. It can only tell you to use some other method to look for the limit or show it does not exist.

What's more concerning is that these kind of ...teachers are all over the place and students who aren't as bright as the OP will not notice that they are tought nonsense.

Everyone gets things wrong every once in a while.

Your argument is completely correct.
To summarize the argument so it can be voted on:

Whenever $3\leq x\leq 6$,
$g(x) = 5$.

Therefore whenever $3\leq x\leq 6$,
$h(x) = f(g(x)) = f(5) = 0$.

Therefore whenever $3<x<6$,
$h'(x) = 0$.

Therefore $h'(4)=0$.


You could also go directly from step 2 to step 4 via an epsilon-delta argument.
In other words, this is a very basic fact.
On the other hand, since $f'(5)$ is not a real number, the conditions to apply the chain rule are not satisfied and you cannot conclude anything at all (not even “the derivative of $h$ is undefined”) using the chain rule.
Yes, your generalization holds as well; we can make the same sequence of statements for arbitrary $a,b,k$ with $a<b$ as for $3,6,5$ respectively.
(Community wiki because nearly everyone here is thinking the same thing.)

The teacher's mistake is the same as in the following example: Consider the sequence $c_n = a_n - b_n$, where $a_n=n$ and $b_n = n$. Then $\lim_n c_n = \infty - \infty$ is not defined, so $(c_n)$ does not converge.

It is quite similar to the 2 examples in the addendum to my answer , while it is the same as my very last comment there concerning $0x = 0$ , even when variable $x$ is unbounded.
